# Template or style for a WP7 Portrait Or Landscape application

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, expression-blend, windows-phone-7.1

I would create a template for that element of my page to function properly in horizontal and link this to an event.
In ExpressionBlend if possible ...
Could you point me to a solution please?

[Portrait http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/972/recorderl.png](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/972/recorderl.png)
[Landscape http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/8517/landscapei.png](http://img803.imageshack.us/img803/8517/landscapei.png)